# How to delete a DocuSign Clickwrap Agreement using an agreement_id

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Our application uses DocuSign Clickwrap Agreements for our user onboarding process. The agreements are generated using DocuSign's Click API in our React Application. However, we want to add an endpoint in our Express.js backend that allows us to delete or void a user's agreement using the agreement_id generated when they first sign the agreement.

We tried using the [docusign-click](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docusign-click) node client, which is supposed to be the official DocuSign Click API module for node. However, DocuSign's documentation mentions nothing of the kind of function we require. [Official Documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/accounts/clickwraps/). But there's a twist, if I try to use the library like below, I can find the ClickwrapDeleteResponse() function in the intellisense, but there's no description of the function, idk what arguments to pass, nothing whatsoever.

```js
const docusignClick = require('docusign-click');
docusignClick.ClickwrapDeleteResponse()
```

I need to know if there's a method, could be an API method from the library, or even an endpoint that I can hit with the required credentials, to delete a clickwrap agreement signed by a user.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no means to delete a clickwrap agreement at this time. Either via the web app, or via the API. This is not functionality currently offered by DocuSign.
If this is a requirement you may want to use eSignature instead of Click. Envelopes can be deleted.
Another option is to create a clickwrap for each agreement. Clickwraps can be deleted. This approach is more cumbersome, requires more API calls, and also does not collate together all agreements based on the clickwrap.

Comment: Ahh that's a bummer. We don't really want to create a new clickwrap for every user, it would be very cumbersome just like you said, and very counterproductive for our current setup. I guess the only option now is to request the DocuSign devs to add this whenever possible. Until then we'll do what we can with what we have.

Comment: Thanks Khizar, if you can go to https://feedback.docusign.com/ and submit this feature request - that would be great